# Find the lowest value of php foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach, min

I am trying to extract the lower (but not 0) of two figures produced by the following code. This code loops twice giving two figures. I only want the lower of the two. I can see that I should be using min(array) but I can't really see where to start.

```
foreach ($objResult->ProductGroups as $objProductGroup)
{
    if ($objProductGroup->hasProductQuote)
    {
        foreach ($objProductGroup->ProductQuotes as $objProductQuote)
        {
            if (!$objProductQuote->hasErrors)
            {   
                printf("<div>&pound;%01.2f</div>", $objProductQuote->Figures->RegularPayment);  
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the quotes as you get to them, append them to an array. Then you can use `min` afterward to print the lower of the two.

```
$quotes = [];
foreach ($objResult->ProductGroups as $objProductGroup)
{
    if ($objProductGroup->hasProductQuote)
    {
        foreach ($objProductGroup->ProductQuotes as $objProductQuote)
        {
            if (!$objProductQuote->hasErrors)
            {
                $quotes[] = $objProductQuote->Figures->RegularPayment;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("<div>&pound;%01.2f</div>", min($quotes));
```

Comment: That almost has it, but this code is itself looped several times within the page and if the previous min($quotes) result is lower it shows as the next one.

Comment: @SteveAsh That should be fixed if you reinitialize `$quotes` before each round. I updated the answer.